# Double Output in PHP Built-In Webserver

Tags: php

I have a small PHP program

```
#File: test.php
<?php
echo "echo";
file_put_contents('php://stdout', 'this is a test' . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

I'm running this program with the PHP built-in web server (PHP 7.1.21, installed via homebrew, if it matters).

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8081 test.php
```

My expectation is that, web a web-page is requested via `http://127.0.0.1:8081`, that PHP will echo the word `echo` out to the browser, and PHP will echo the sentence `this is a test` out to the console running the build-in web server.

And this *almost* happens -- expect that `this is a test` is printed to stdout *twice* for each request.  Does anyone know what might be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by having my program log the following

```
file_put_contents('php://stdout', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
```

and seeing the following in my console output

```
/
/favicon.ico
```

The second log was from the web-browser automatically trying to grab a `favicon.ico` file.

Answer (score 1):

The way you started the built-in webserver is not correct. You added the test `test.php` file at the end, which means the `test.php` file should act as a route file.

Just start the built-in webserver with the following command:

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:8081
```

The command starts the webserver inside the current working directory and sets it as the webroot. Open your browser with the url: `http://127.0.0.1:8081/test.php`

Some more details about the built-in webserver can be found [here](https://stefanhuber.at/posts/php-builtin-webserver/).